# Apache Camel throws java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull

Tags: java, groovy, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have a groovy script that I'm trying to get going; it's job is to read one message queue, and then re-queue the messages into a new set of MQs we are putting live.

Here's the code:

```
@Grab(group='org.apache.camel', module='camel-core', version='2.11.0')
@Grab(group='org.apache.activemq', module='activemq-core', version='5.7.0')
@Grab(group='org.apache.activemq', module='activemq-camel', version='5.8.0')
@Grab(group='ch.qos.logback', module='logback-classic', version='1.0.13')


import org.apache.activemq.camel.component.ActiveMQComponent
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory
import org.apache.camel.CamelContext
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext

class CopyFromOneServerToAnother extends RouteBuilder{

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final CamelContext camelContext = new DefaultCamelContext();

    camelContext.addComponent("jms-01", ActiveMQComponent.activeMQComponent("tcp://mq01:61616"));

    try {
        // Add the routes defined below to the camel context
        camelContext.addRoutes(new CopyFromOneServerToAnother());
        camelContext.start();
        Thread.sleep(10000000);
    }
    catch (final Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            camelContext.stop();
        }
        catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    /// The name of the AMQ instance and queue where message will be taken from
    from("jms-01:TEST-1")
            .log("Processed")
            // Final resting point for each message.
            .to("jms-01:TEST-3")
            .end();
}
}
```

So, this is using the same broker for source and destination, but different queues.

This reads the messages, however throws an exception when trying to write them:

```
15:15:31.548 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[TEST-1]] INFO  route1 - Processed
15:15:31.548 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[TEST-1]] DEBUG o.a.camel.processor.SendProcessor - >>>> Endpoint[jms-01://TEST-3] Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:mq01.dummycorp.corp-60083-1370438794752-5:131:1:1:1]]
15:15:31.594 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[TEST-1]] DEBUG o.a.c.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:mq01.dummycorp.corp-60083-1370438794752-5:131:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-ukm038662-local-53821-1370441730008-0-10). On delivery attempt: 0 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:mq01.dummycorp.corp-60083-1370438794752-5:131:1:1:1]]
15:15:31.595 [Camel (camel-1) thread #0 - JmsConsumer[TEST-1]] ERROR o.a.c.processor.DefaultErrorHandler - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID:mq01.dummycorp.corp-60083-1370438794752-5:131:1:1:1 on ExchangeId: ID-ukm038662-local-53821-1370441730008-0-10). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:mq01.dummycorp.corp-60083-1370438794752-5:131:1:1:1]]
org.apache.camel.CamelExecutionException: Exception occurred during execution on the exchange: Exchange[JmsMessage[JmsMessageID: ID:mq01.dummycorp.corp-60083-1370438794752-5:131:1:1:1]]
  at org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.wrapCamelExecutionException(ObjectHelper.java:1354) ~[camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultExchange.setException(DefaultExchange.java:272) ~[camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:137) ~[camel-jms-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
  at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122) ~[camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:298) ~[camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:117) ~[camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.BacklogTracerInterceptor.process(BacklogTracerInterceptor.java:84) ~[camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:91) ~[camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.processErrorHandler(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:390) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:273) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.DefaultChannel.process(DefaultChannel.java:335) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:117) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:80) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteContextProcessor.processNext(RouteContextProcessor.java:46) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.processAsync(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:150) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.UnitOfWorkProcessor.process(UnitOfWorkProcessor.java:117) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.processNext(RouteInflightRepositoryProcessor.java:48) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:99) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:90) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:72) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:99) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:86) [camel-core-2.11.0.jar:2.11.0]
  at org.apache.camel.component.jms.EndpointMessageListener.onMessage(EndpointMessageListener.java:104) [camel-jms-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:562) [spring-jms-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:500) [spring-jms-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doExecuteListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:468) [spring-jms-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:326) [spring-jms-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(AbstractPollingMessageListenerContainer.java:264) [spring-jms-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.invokeListener(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1071) [spring-jms-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.executeOngoingLoop(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:1063) [spring-jms-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
  at org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageListenerInvoker.run(DefaultMessageListenerContainer.java:960) [spring-jms-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_21]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_21]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) [na:1.7.0_21]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.camel.util.ObjectHelper.notNull(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/String;)V
  at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsBinding.makeJmsMessage(JmsBinding.java:285) ~[camel-jms-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
  at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer$2.createMessage(JmsProducer.java:270) ~[camel-jms-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
  at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.doSendToDestination(JmsConfiguration.java:216) ~[camel-jms-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
  at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.access$100(JmsConfiguration.java:159) ~[camel-jms-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
  at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate$1.doInJms(JmsConfiguration.java:173) ~[camel-jms-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
  at org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate.execute(JmsTemplate.java:466) ~[spring-jms-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
  at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsConfiguration$CamelJmsTemplate.send(JmsConfiguration.java:170) ~[camel-jms-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
  at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.doSend(JmsProducer.java:402) ~[camel-jms-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
  at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.processInOnly(JmsProducer.java:356) ~[camel-jms-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
  at org.apache.camel.component.jms.JmsProducer.process(JmsProducer.java:132) ~[camel-jms-2.10.3.jar:2.10.3]
  ... 49 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 8):

This smells like you have multiple different versions of camel JARs on the classpath. Can you double check that thet camel JARs are ALL the SAME version.

Answer (score 7):

I just stumbled on the same problem. Adding this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-jms</artifactId>
    <version>${camel.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

to my pom fixed it. Without that, an older (than my other camel libraries) version of that library was used - as suggested by Claus in another answer

Comment: Careful - some of the camel examples use `${camel-version}` instead of `${camel.version}`

Comment: @Jan - it doesn't really make a difference, it's just how you declare the variable in your pom file

Comment: Thank you!! This solved my issue after scouring the internet for 30 minutes!

Comment: <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId> might be an even better pick if you more extensively make use of camel in your application, and will insure that this same problem will not arise using other resources within the camel library of an older / incompatible version.